# Evaluation metric for imbalanced data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, unbalanced-classes, model-evaluation, anomaly-detection

Hi I'm a CS graduate student

I have a question for AI or data experts. I'm writing a paper

My dataset is time-series sensor data and anomaly (positive class) ratio is between 5% and 6%

you can see the picture below. I used *classification_report* in *sklearn* library

[image]

But, I'm confused as to what value to report in my evaluation section ...

I think it is reasonable to report f1-score with macro avg (0.40)

Is it ok?

Thank you for your explanation !

Comment: Use the metric you see being used in similar work. // Statisticians prefer proper scoring rules that are not based on thresholds. Log loss and Brier score are two common examples. [You might be interested in this link.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he)